# Active link not changing color

Tags: javascript, html, css

My navigation links are in layout page and they look like:

```
<h3 id="my-navigation">
   <a href="@Url.Action("Questions", "Question")">ANKETA</a>
   <a href="@Url.Action("Statistics","Administrator")">STATISTIKA</a>
   ...
</h3>
```

I need active link to change color. CSS to achieve this:

```
#my-navigation a.active {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#E0EBEB;
}
```

Since there are no navigation links in all html pages, but just in layout, I tried with javascript:

```
$('#my-navigation a').click(function () {
    $('#my-navigation a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Why doesn't this work?

EDIT: 
I realised that this gives effect just temporary (at the time of click). For example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#my-navigation a').click(function () {
        $('#my-navigation a').addClass('active');
    });
});
```

blinks all links on click. So, what to do?

Comment: Works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/seyenaz/q5xv9yqp/

Comment: Are you handling the default behaviour elsewhere, or are you loading a new page when you click the link? (I have no idea what `"@Url.Action(...)"` resolves to.)

Comment: My guess is that you have an error somewhere else that is stopping the js execution, check the developer console for errors and provide more info please.

Comment: Try changing it to `$('#my-navigation a').on('click', function() { $(this).addClass('active'); });`

Comment: @Mave It is nothing new, and it doesn't work permanently in my case.

Comment: If the links do go to a new page, your best bet would be manually adding the class to whichever link corresponds with the page.  Using Javascript in this way is more geared towards links that have been modified to stay on the same page.

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery script you've included works just fine on my end, so I'd say the issue is most likely either with the version of jQuery you've linked on your page or the script being loaded before the links fully render.

Try surrounding the script you listed with a document ready like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#my-navigation a').click(function () {
        $('#my-navigation a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

It is also acceptable to replace the first line with the shorthand version:

```
$(function() {
```

This will ensure the page's content is fully loaded before it assigns the on click trigger to the links, as the links must exist prior to that being defined.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work, at least it works here: https://jsfiddle.net/kvk1keds/
I just changed the click method for

```
$('#my-navigation a').on('click', function (ev) {});
```

You should make sure that the method is running and the class 'active' is being set.

Comment: It takes effect just temporary, at the time of click. For example: $('#my-navigation a').click(function () {
    $('#my-navigation a').addClass('active');
}); blinks all links on click.